# Is the effect of a mending cantrip a continuous spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Suppose I have split a stone brick in two, hollowed it out, packed it full of contraband, and then sealed it shut with a Mending cantrip. How does the spell effect work? Is it a one-and-done, ending when the affected object is repaired, or does it continuously keeping the object's pieces together?

Will Detect Magic pick up the brick?

Could the brick be opened by a Dispel Magic?

Would the effect cease inside an Antimagic Field? Will it resume once the brick is out of the field?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## *Mending* has an instantaneous duration

The duration of [*Mending*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mending) is instantaneous so its effect is not ongoing. Since there is no ongoing magic a mended brick would not be detected by *Detect Magic*, could not be opened by *Dispel Magic*, and would not be broken by an antimagic field.

There are some spells, such as *[Ceremony](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/ceremony)*, or [*Heroes Feast*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/heroes-feast) that are instantaneous but can create a prolonged effect. These spells, however, have clearly defined durations as a part of the spells text.

Other spells, such as *[Leomund's Secret Chest](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/leomunds-secret-chest)*, and *[Goodberry](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/goodberry)* do not have a clearly defined end to their duration<sup>1</sup> but have some mechanism that degrade their magic power over time.

Functionally there is a bit of a grey area with regards to instantaneous spells with enduring effects but as a rule unless the nature of the effect is unambiguously magical (ie. being able to conjure a chest from the ethereal plane) it is best considered nonmagical.

<sup>1:The berries from *Goodberry* never disappear they just lose their potency</sup>

Answer (score 6):

The [spell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mending)'s duration is Instantaneous, meaning that the magic is effected in a single burst and does not linger. This is similar to instantaneous healing and damage spells, except this spell heals an object's damage. As such, there is no magic left to be detected  or otherwise affected by spells which interact with active magic.

[Prestidigitation](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/prestidigitation) is an example of a spell that has effects which remain active for a given time period, and which makes explicit mention of only non-instantaneous effects lingering after the spell is cast. Such spells typically last for their stated  duration or until dispelled.